# Open an image/pdf/docx/video in a listview with appropiate external applications in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, assets, intentfilter

I have an image/pdf/docx/video as part of a listview item. I want to open them with appropriate applications in android. Currently only the video seem to open properly. Rest does not work. Can someone kindly help me !!!

Here is my code snippet I use from onItemClick in a ListView:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(itemPath), "*/*");
//intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

I tried :

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(itemPath), "image/*");
```

for image files and

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(itemPath), "application/pdf");
```

for pdf files too. But none work.

Thanks.

Comment: What does "none work" mean? What happens when you run your app with the changes described in your question?

Comment: It does not work !!!

Comment: Please provide more details so that we can help you.

Comment: When I use intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(itemPath), "image/*"); it opens up the default imageviwer on android ,but it does not open the image, it gives "No media found" message. And when I use intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(itemPath), "application/pdf"); for opening pdf files, it does not invoke any application at all.

Comment: Please edit your original question with the information from your last comment. You should also include the value of `itemPath` in both cases.